Adding Base64 Images to a Docx in JS (or with a library)
I'm trying to code a little tool for my brother whom is a carpenter and i'm a bit stuck on one part of the process. (sorry for my english i'm not native)
Context : So the employees of my brother have to creates some files that can contains a lot of reports each reports have its own fields etc etc. So i did a form where you give your basic informations then you select the number of reports you want to make then when you are done with all your reports you can generate a docx of your file.
What i used: I used Docx templater to create a template of docx which is populated by my fields (everything is in JS) i'm not familiar at all with node so i included all the libs using  and it worked so far.
So for the text it is working so far my code is populating the fields that are {between} and using the conditionning of docxtemplater.
The problem i have is for those reports a lot of picture have to be included in order to prove the state of things but i didn't see at first that docxtemplater in order to use images you have to pay a license of 500$ a year. (and i don't have the money for that ahahah) So i was able for now to store all of those pictures into array in base64 with clear id stating the field the number of report and all and also placing in the document the same id as the picture where it should appear.
But know i'm stuck because when i generate my docx i can see $1_1_picture_rooftile but i don't know how to replace it with the base64 image stored in my array as key:  1_1_picture_rooftile related to base64 code of the image.
My goal is to after i generate the docx using docxtemplater and FileSaver take the output document and parse all those images tags i generated and replace those with the corresponding image.
I don't know if i make sense but here is my code https://www.mediafire.com/file/eqidvjvsmrc1kr5/macullo8safe.rar/file
And this is my generate function at the end :
function generate() {
    collectImages();
    // Retrieve values from the form fields on page1
    const nom = document.getElementById('nom')?.value || '';
    const prenom = document.getElementById('prenom')?.value || '';
    const posteElement = document.querySelector('input[name="poste"]:checked');
    const numeroChantier = document.getElementById('numeroChantier')?.value || '';
    const address = document.getElementById('address')?.value || '';
    const city = document.getElementById('city')?.value || '';
    const postalCode = document.getElementById('postalCode')?.value || '';
    const hasNumeroChantierElement = document.querySelector('input[name="hasNumeroChantier"]:checked');

    // Check if the elements exist and log missing elements
    if (!posteElement) console.error('Element with name "poste" is missing or not checked.');
    if (!hasNumeroChantierElement) console.error('Element with name "hasNumeroChantier" is missing or not checked.');

    // If any required element is missing, stop execution
    if (!posteElement || !hasNumeroChantierElement) {
        console.error('Required form elements are missing.');
        return;
    }

    const poste = posteElement.value;
    const hasNumeroChantier = hasNumeroChantierElement.value === 'true';

    // Store current report data
    storeCurrentReportData();

    // Log the data to verify
    console.log({
        nom: nom,
        prenom: prenom,
        poste: poste,
        numeroChantier: numeroChantier,
        address: address,
        city: city,
        postalCode: postalCode,
        hasNumeroChantier: hasNumeroChantier,
        reports: reportsDataArray
    });

    // Load the DOCX template
    loadFile('./template.docx', function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        const zip = new PizZip(content);
        const doc = new window.docxtemplater(zip, {
            paragraphLoop: true,
            linebreaks: true
        });


        // Create a data object with the retrieved values and report data
        const emptyTab = [];
        const fullTab = [];

        fullTab.push({"name":"toto"});
        fullTab.push({"name":"eliott"});


        const dataTab={
            empty:emptyTab,
            full:fullTab
        };


        const data = {
            nom: nom,
            prenom: prenom,
            poste: poste,
            numeroChantier: numeroChantier,
            address: address,
            city: city,
            postalCode: postalCode,
            hasNumeroChantier: hasNumeroChantier,
            reports: reportsDataArray
        };

        // Set the data in the template
        doc.setData(data);

        try {
            // Render the document
            doc.render();
        } catch (error) {
            const e = {
                message: error.message,
                name: error.name,
                stack: error.stack,
                properties: error.properties,
            };
            console.log(JSON.stringify({ error: e }, null, 2));
            throw error;
        }


                const out = doc.getZip().generate({ type: 'blob' });
                saveAs(out, 'output.docx');
    });
}

